# Unable to extract zip file which generated using php

Tags: php, zip, archive, php-ziparchive

I have written the PHP script to generate the zip file. it's working fine when I use rar software to extract it but not getting extract with rar software. I can't ask to users to install rar software to extract downloaded zip file.

I don't know where i am commiting mistakes.
Here i attached error screen shot which i get when try to open zip file.
[image: Opening zip file without using any software]

```
// Here is code snippet
$obj->create_zip($files_to_zip, $dir . '/download.zip');

// Code for create_zip function
//create the archive
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open($destination, $overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
    return false;
}
//add the files
foreach ($valid_files as $file) {    
    $filearr = explode('/', $file);
    $zip->addFile($file, end($filearr));
}
$zip->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

If $valid_files is a glob'd array, use basename() instead of end(), your zip might not actually have added any files causing for it to be an invalid zip (however that would be visible in the size of the zip file).

Also try winrar/winzip/7zip and see what they return, microsoft's internal zip engine might not be up to date enough to open the zips.

Comment: Thanks, I just removed white spaces from top of the page and HTML and it works perfectly.

Comment: @AmitSinha can you elaborate on that please? I am having the same problem but I am not sure why would white spaces in php script influence the generated file.

Answer (score 1):

I have also encountered this problem, using **7z** solved the problem but we need to send the zip to somebody else so 7z is a nono.

I found that, in my case it is that the file path is too long:

**When I use this:**

```
$zip->addFile($files_path.'/people.txt');
```

And it generated a zip folder nested very deep e.g. ["/tmp/something/something1/something2/people.txt"]

**So I need to use this instead**

```
$zip->addFile($files_path.'/people.txt', 'people.txt');
```

Which generate a a zip folder with only 1 layer ["people.txt"], and Windows Zip read perfectly~

Hope this helps somebody that also have this problem!

Comment: Thanks.  Just had this exact same problem and someone pointed me here.